# How do you email Swift automation test results?

Tags: xcode, email, automation, xctest

I would like to be able to email my automation test results to my team. I am not sure how to get this done so a point in the right direction would be really helpful. I have found code that will be able to send out an email, however to fill the body with the results I would need to know the file that xCode is storing them in, which I am not able to find.

This is just ideas that I am throwing out there, if there is a better way to go about this I am all ears.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ui automation test results are in plist format (TestSummaries.plist) so you need to parse this plist file to extract the test result.
We are using [trainer](https://rubygems.org/gems/trainer) gem to convert results to junit xml format. I think it would be good starting point for you to use above gem and attach xml file in your email.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into running your suite on Jenkins server. There is an option you can set up to send result to an email address. However be warned that since xcode 8 has been release Jenkins and Xcode are not the best of friends.